# For legacy code, is there a better patch for RasterArray than Raster?

Tags: graphics, front-end

Notice the time calculation around the graphics in the code below.  That is taking 6 seconds which seems like a problem.

````
(* for 3-tuple from list of eight:  8x 8x 8 = 512; + 20 padding = 532 \
*)


f = 2; (* number of images *)

name = Table[i, {i, 1, f}];

For[loop = 1, loop <= f, loop++,
 
 bckrow =.;
 bckcol =.;
 sum =.;
 
 bckrow = Table[{x, y}, {x, 1, 532}, {y, 1, 532}];
 bckcol = Table[{x, y}, {x, 1, 532}, {y, 1, 532}];
 
 
 
 bckrow[[All, All]] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
 bckcol[[All, All]] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
 tup = Tuples[{
    Random[Real, {(-1.0 + (loop/400)), -0.25}, 4],
    Random[Real, {(-1.0 + (loop/400)), -0.25}, 4],
    Random[Real, {(0 + (loop/100)), 1.0}, 4],
    Random[Real, {(0 + (loop/100)), 1.0}, 4],
    Random[Real, {(1.0 - (loop/100)), 0.0}, 4],
    Random[Real, {(1.0 - (loop/100)), 0.0}, 4],
    Random[Real, {0.25, (1.0 - (loop/400))}, 4],
    Random[Real, {0.25, (1.0 - (loop/400))}, 4]},
   3];
 
 For[j = 1, j <= 512, j++, bckcol[[All, j]] = tup[[j]]];
 For[i = 1, i <= 512, i++, bckrow[[i, All]] = tup[[i]]];
 
 sum = bckrow + bckcol;
 
 For[i = 1, i <= 532, i++, For[j = 1, j <= 532, j++,
   If[((0 > sum[[i, j, 1]]) || (sum[[i, j, 1]] > 1) ||
      (0 > sum[[i, j, 2]]) || (sum[[i, j, 2]] > 1) ||
      (0 > sum[[i, j, 3]]) || (sum[[i, j, 3]] > 1)),
    ( sum[[i, j, 1]] = sum[[i, j, 2]] = sum[[i, j, 3]] = 0)]]];
 
 t1 = AbsoluteTime[];
 Print[Graphics[Raster[sum], ImageSize -> {532, 532}]] ;
 t2 = AbsoluteTime[];
 t = t2 - t1;
 Print[t]
 ] (* ] = First For in program *)
```
````

Comment: I don't think your problem is `Raster`, but the visualization of the results. If you remove the Print statement from `Print[Graphics[...]]`, and use `RepeatedTiming` on the whole loop, the entire loop only takes 3.1 s. If you add back the `Print` to show the images, and use AbsoluteTiming on the whole loop, it takes 13 seconds. I think producing the visual output is the most time consuming part here.

Comment: OK, so we have it down to the Print statement.  Why would printing a 532 x 532 RGB image take so long?  I frequently run 1000 x 1000 in other programs and do not notice a delay when I use MatrixPlot.

Comment: Have you tried Image instead of Raster?

Comment: Image works if I get rid of Table.  Using ```RandomReal[{0, 0}, {532, 532, 3}]``` strangely helps speed.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to answer my own question, but v6 to v12 is a complete rewrite, and it runs quickly:

```
bckrow =.;
bckcol =.;
sum =.;

bckrow = RandomReal[{0, 0}, {532, 532, 3}];
bckcol = RandomReal[{0, 0}, {532, 532, 3}];

tup = Tuples[{
    Random[Real, {(-1.0 + (loop/400)), -0.25}, 4],
    Random[Real, {(-1.0 + (loop/400)), -0.25}, 4],
    Random[Real, {(0 + (loop/100)), 1.0}, 4],
    Random[Real, {(0 + (loop/100)), 1.0}, 4],
    Random[Real, {(1.0 - (loop/100)), 0.0}, 4],
    Random[Real, {(1.0 - (loop/100)), 0.0}, 4],
    Random[Real, {0.25, (1.0 - (loop/400))}, 4],
    Random[Real, {0.25, (1.0 - (loop/400))}, 4]},
   3];

For[j = 1, j <= 512, j++, bckcol[[All, j]] = tup[[j]]];
For[i = 1, i <= 512, i++, bckrow[[i, All]] = tup[[i]]];

sum = bckrow + bckcol;

For[i = 1, i <= 532, i++, For[j = 1, j <= 532, j++,
   If[((0 > sum[[i, j, 1]]) || (sum[[i, j, 1]] > 1) ||
      (0 > sum[[i, j, 2]]) || (sum[[i, j, 2]] > 1) ||
      (0 > sum[[i, j, 3]]) || (sum[[i, j, 3]] > 1)),
    ( sum[[i, j, 1]] = sum[[i, j, 2]] = sum[[i, j, 3]] = 0)]]];

ImageRotate[Image[sum], 90 \[Degree]]
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach without `For` loops:

```
SeedRandom[1]
loop = 1;
{range1, range2} = {{1/4, 1 - loop/400}, {loop/100, 1}};

tupB = Tuples[Random[Real, #, 4] & /@ {- Reverse @ range1, - Reverse @ range1, range2, 
    range2, 1 - range2, 1 - range2, range1, range1}, 3]; 

sumB = ConstantArray[0, {532, 532, 3}];

sumB[[;; Length @ tupB, All]] = tupB;

sumB = Reverse[sumB + Transpose[sumB]];

sumB = Map[Boole[And @@ (0 <= # <= 1 & /@ #)] # &, sumB, {-2}];

Image[sumB]
```

[image]